# ngx.shared.DICT.incr is atomic?

Tags: nginx, lua

I need a global counter to stat http request num and do some redirect work rely on the counter. I store the global counter at the ngx_lua module's shared memory through the directive lua_shared_dict,then access the counter and increase it through the API ngx.shared.DICT.incr on every work process of nginx. I'm puzzled that is there need a lock mechanism to protected the counter variable,or the ngx.shared.DICT.incr api is atomic? I cannot find answer from the offical document.

Comment: I believe it is atomic, cos that seems to be the sole purpose of providing an extra operation like this.

Answer (score 3):

All operations on `ngx.shared.DICT` are atomic. See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/openresty-en/EWMjz5Zzj1E/discussion).